# Learning Nested loops in zybooks

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int userNum;
   int i;
   int j;

   scanf("%d", &userNum);

   for(i = 0; i <= userNum; ++i) {
     printf("%d\n",i);
     for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
        printf(" ");
     }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

It is supposed to print:

```
0
 1
  2
   3
```

But it prints it with an extra line of spaces.

Comment: Try to rearrange your outer loop so that you end the loop writing a `'\n'` (not a space like in your question): `/* pseudo-code */ for (i) { printspaces(); printnumber(); printnewline(); }`

Comment: Print the spaces before you print the number. You will need to alter the loop conditions slightly.

Comment: @wobr I think you can make an answer which would be worth being accepted.

Comment: Use `putchar (' ');` to output a single `space` No conversions involved so `printf` isn't needed (even though a good compiler will optimize that for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print the number and new line after printing spaces like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int userNum;
   int i;
   int j;

   scanf("%d", &userNum);

   for(i = 0; i <= userNum; ++i) {
     for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        printf(" ");
     }
     printf("%d\n",i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Robert Henry, you correctly point out that the result of this answer is incorrect and then you accept it, though there is another answer which does it correctly. Admittedly the other answer is mine, so I am in a slightly awkward situation, but I have to ask: Why?

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the digit first and then a number of blanks which is one more than the digit you are currently working on.
Turn that around, i.e. first print appropriatly many blanks, THEN print the digit.
And appropriatly many blanks is only as many as the digit you are printing, i.e. one fewer than you currently do. I.e. none for the first "0", then one for "1".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int userNum=0; // init, to have a default in case of failing scanf()
   int i;
   int j;

   scanf("%d", &userNum); // you should check the return value here...

   for(i = 0; i <= userNum; ++i)
   {
     for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) // "<" instead of "<=" makes one fewer
     { 
        printf(" ");
     }
     printf("%d\n",i); // afterwards
   }
   return 0;
}
```

By the way, I recommend to get into the habit of checking the returnvalue (not the scanned value) of `scanf()`. Writing code without that, makes the program vulnerable against wrong syntac input.

Comment: Really helpful info on using `scanf()`. Might sound a little cynical, but is really helpful: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html